# Unable to access Windows folder after clicking on Browse button

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
 IWebElement browseButton = driver.FindElement(By.Name("file"));
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
 js.ExecuteScript("$(arguments[0]).click();", browseButton);         
 String pathToGetFile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

---

Here, I am able to click on the browse button which has a jquery attribute attached to it. After the click, Windows folder opens successfully but the file is not being selected from this path. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does 'GetCurrentDirectory()' gives you path to file or path to parent folder?

Comment: GetCurrentDirectory() gives path to parent folder

Comment: so that means you are trying to upload the folder and not file?

Answer (score 1):

I hope the overall objective is to upload/download file. Selenium cannot interact with Windows popup. For this objective you might want to use Robot or AutoIT to automate further. Since [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) is a part of java package, you can checkout AutoIT